# ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

I am working though a jupyter notebook on udemy, this topic is on pandas, on one of the questions I get this error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-dc8b64eb545d> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_html('http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')

c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only)
    985                   decimal=decimal, converters=converters, na_values=na_values,
    986                   keep_default_na=keep_default_na,
--> 987                   displayed_only=displayed_only)

c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only, **kwargs)
    791     retained = None
    792     for flav in flavor:
--> 793         parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
    794         p = parser(io, compiled_match, attrs, encoding, displayed_only)
    795 

c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py in _parser_dispatch(flavor)
    749     else:
    750         if not _HAS_LXML:
--> 751             raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
    752     return _valid_parsers[flavor]
    753 

ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

(I am using python 3.7, I have downloaded anaconda)

I then tried to install lxml in the command prompt using:

```
pip3 install lxml
```

however I get this error message:

```
Command "c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PHILLI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i762jowc\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\PHILLI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z7kvhhca\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PHILLI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i762jowc\lxml\
```

I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure that `c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32` is the python version that came with your anaconda? If not, then delete it and amke sure that your anaconda is in your PATH

Comment: File it as a bug with Udemy as well: they should have told how to install lxml. The thing is that lxml needs a C library as well; pip won't install that. Try with `conda` instead: `conda install lxml`.

Comment: Do you use Anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Anaconda Navigator from there click Environments select one that you are working on currently and install package from there. The reason is that your jupyter notebook does not use your default python installation. And using only `pip3` command in terminal without switching to correct environment won't work. Plus I had my share of problems with installing from Anaconda terminal.

**EDIT**

Installing from navigator will also install all needed dependencies including C libraries. It really is the easiest way of managing packages in your jupyter/Anaconda project.

**EDIT2**

From your comments I have a feeling your jupyter notebook uses different python environment. Anaconda comes with python 3.6 not 3.7. Plus the path in your error:

```
Command "c:\users\phillip.desktop-did4ci8\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\PHILLI~1.DES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i762jowc\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\PHILLI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z7kvhhca\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PHILLI~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i762jowc\lxml\
```

suggest different environment than the Anaconda base(root). Try lunching jupyter from navigator this will ensure you are using the correct environment

Comment: There is only one environment there, base (root), and lxml is installed on it.

Comment: Try to reinstall it from there your previous attempts might have broken something

Comment: One more question Anconda does not come with python 3.7 how is it possible you are using it in jupyter? Try launching jupyter from navigator

Comment: Thanks, running it through the anaconda navigator fixed this, I'm not sure why I was having this issue when running jupyter through the command prompt

Comment: As stated in my answer running it from terminal uses your default environment which is python 3.7 and not the one from Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Use the anaconda environment to install the missing package.

Steps:

1. Go to the anaconda console
2. Ensure you switch to the environment being used to run the script on the bar to the right of "Applications on" at the top of the page.
3. Click on Environments, on the left side bar
4. Type the name of the package - "lxml" - in this case
5. Switch the dropdown button  from "Installed" to "Not installed"
6. Once the package shows up, tick the checkbox
7. Click Apply at the bottom of the screen
8. Once installed, go back to your page and relaunch jupyter notebook.

That should do the trick.